# Nodejs Cognito cognitoUser.authenticateUser() getting 502 bad gateway on lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have an api call that is supposed to use the Cognito Javascript SDK to authenticate the user. It is not working when deployed to lambda, but works locally. Why isn't this working?

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {

  var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: req.body.username,
    Password: req.body.password
  });
  var userData = {
    Username: req.body.username,
    Pool: userPool
  };
   try {

     var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
     cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
       onSuccess: function (result) {
         res.status(200);
         res.send({ token: `${result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()}` });
       },
       onFailure: function (err) {
         res.status(401);
         res.send({ "Message": "Login failed, please try again" });
       }
     });
   }
   catch (ex) {
     res.status(500);
     res.send({
       "message": "error logging in",
       "error": ex
     });
   }
});
```

is returning

```
---502 bad gateway
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The real issue was nothing to do with lambda or the deployment or permissions as I thought it would be. 
It was really a timeout issue.

I increased my lambda memory and that sped it up a bit and made the call come back successfully.

Options 1) increase ram 2) increase the timeout limit

Comment: Thanks for this. Tried so many other ways to get a response but when i saw this it clicked. The logs shows that my lambda was timing out right on 3 seconds which is the default when created using aws-cdk. Increasing the timeout variable for the lambda worked

Comment: Thanks Jyaesh, I got it when i increased the memory and timeout.. Guys you can increase these things from aws console: go to the lambda function and General Configuration. You can edit the memory size and timeout from there. Or if you are using SAM template or CFT, then change it like this:Runtime: nodejs10.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 5
      FunctionName: LoginAuthenticationFn